# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE; expected 1, got 0. Cant determine the error from code

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-jdbc

//set input parameters

```
Map<String,Object> inParams = new HashMap<String,Object>();
inParams.put("Sig",resourceHistoryBean.getId());

List<ResourceHistoryBean> resourceHistoryList= new ArrayList<ResourceHistoryBean>();
```

// define stored procedure

```
try{        
    SimpleJdbcCall readResult = new SimpleJdbcCall(getDataSource())
            .useInParameterNames("Sig")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("Sig", Types.VARCHAR))
            .withProcedureName("SP_ResourceAllocationDtls")
            .withSchemaName("hrms")
            .returningResultSet("ResourceHistory", new ParameterizedRowMapper<ResourceHistoryBean>() {
                public ResourceHistoryBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                        throws SQLException {
                    ResourceHistoryBean bean = new ResourceHistoryBean();
                    resourceHistoryBean.setProjectName(rs.getString(RH_PROJECT_NAME));
                    return bean;
                }
            });
    readResult.compile();
```

// execute stored procedure

```
Map<String, Object> out = readResult.execute(inParams);
resourceHistoryList = (List<ResourceHistoryBean>) out.get("ResourceHistory");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was able to find an alternative solution to above problem (Parameter passing to stored procedure and use a mapping class as well ):

```
public List<ResourceHistoryBean> getResourceHistory(final ResourceHistoryBean resourceHistoryBean)throws Exception{

    try {
        // call stored procedure and pass parameter to it
        List resourceHistoryList = getJdbcTemplate().query(
                "call hrms.SP_ResourceAllocationDtls(?)",
                new Object[] {resourceHistoryBean.getId()}, new HistoryMapper());
        return resourceHistoryList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        closeTemplate();

    }

}
```

// mapper class

```
class HistoryMapper implements RowMapper, IDatabaseConstants {

public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    ResourceHistoryBean resourceHistoryBean = new ResourceHistoryBean();
    resourceHistoryBean.setProjectName(rs.getString(RH_PROJECT_NAME));
    return resourceHistoryBean;
}
}
```